# \n in the end of line with using print

Tags: swift

When I am using *print* on right toolbar there is text with *\n* on the end. There is not new line for me. What to do to delete this \n . Example

```
print("hello)
```

and I get on right side result like this ***"hello\n"***

Comment: That's just how the Playground sidebar displays it. Open the console window and you'll see the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default terminator for `print` is the newline "\n".

You can specify that you do not want any terminator like this:

```
print("hello", terminator: "")
```

And since you're in a Playground, open the "Debug Area" to see the print result in the console: the side panel is a preview and doesn't work the same way.

For example, this sequence:

```
print("hello")
print("hello", terminator: "")
print("hello")
```

Gives:

> hello
>   hellohello

in the debug area, but will show:

> "hello\n"
>   "hello"
>   "hello\n"

in the preview panel.