# Why does map(_:) in Swift Playground return a String and not a tuple?

Tags: swift, swift3

I am attempting to use Swift Playground to use `map(_:)` and `enumerated()` to walk through an array of `orders`, returning the first perfect match to a customers `goods`.

However, when testing in Swift Playground; the `map(_:)` function returns a string when it should be a tuple.

I'm attempting to retrieve the index and the value; of a given array filter.

Right now, my current solution is this;

```
let orders = [4,2,7]
let goods = 2
var matching:Int = (orders.filter{ $0 == goods }.first) ?? 0 as Int
```

In this example, the answer is `2`; however it doesn't give me the index of the array.

My second attempt in Swift Playground is thus

```
var r = (orders.filter{ $0 == goods }).enumerated().map { (index, element) -> (Int,Int) in
    return (index, element)
}

print (r.first!) // This should report (0,2)
```

However, this in Swift Playground prints out in the sidebar panel

```
"(0, 2)\n"
```

Screenshot:

[image: swift playground]

Why does the sidebar reporting that this is a string?

Is there a way to get the index and element correctly in this example?

Comment: Strongly related: [\n in the end of line with using print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987399/n-in-the-end-of-line-with-using-print)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get Index of Orders that matches Goods**

To get index & element:

```
var r = orders.enumerated().map { ( index, element) -> (Int, Int) in
    return (index, element)
}.filter { (index, element) -> Bool in
    if element == goods {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

or more compact:

```
var r = orders.enumerated().map { index, element in (index, element) }
    .filter { _, element in element == goods ? true : false }

print("r: \(r.first)")
```

Prints:

```
r: (1, 2)
```

If you really want to find the first match only, a for loop is more efficient, as you can `break` after the first match is found.

---

**Playground**

What you see `"(0, 2)\n"` is the result of `print`. What it prints out in console is `(0, 2)` plus newline.

If you want to see the actual value of `r.first!`in the sidebar, remove the print:

```
print (r.first!)
r.first!
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is a for-loop really more efficient; I thought the filters were a good way to replicate the sub-query idea from the old objective c.  But if thats the case; maybe I will use that.

Comment: It is more efficient in the specific case that you want the first match only, as you can `break` the for loop and thus the other `order`s are not processed.

Comment: Understood.  I appreciate your help on this.  I think in the future I will use for-loops; I wanted to use the filter because I thought the solution warranted (a) usage of filters  and (b) I've never done filters before.   Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

The print statement puts your output in `""` and also adds the linebreak `\n` at the end.

If you write `r.first!`, you will see that it actually is a tuple.

Comment: Yes, this was just my confusion. I apologize in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already covered the answer, this is just a side note. I suggest you break down your statement to make it clearer.

```
var r = orders.filter{ $0 == goods }
              .enumerated()
              .map{ index, element in (index, element) }
```

Comment: I will do this from now on. Thanks