# Hiow to obtain enumerated .map values for .filter on lower and higher results, (_:max) applied

Tags: arrays, swift, mapreduce, filtering

Following on from my earlier answered question:

[Why does map(_:) in Swift Playground return a String and not a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41126322/why-does-map-in-swift-playground-return-a-string-and-not-a-tuple)

Given an array of `orders`, a player has a number of `goods` for sale

```
let orders = [2,3,5]
let goods = 1
```

Note: The array should not be ordered.

I'm wanting to apply some equality rules and return an index and value tuple for three rules;

**(a) Perfect match**

> Resolved in earlier question

**(b) When lower number rule is valid**

> The number of goods does not equal to any of the orders;
>   moreover he has fewer goods than the highest order value.
>
> Post-effect: Only return the highest order value && index

In this example, the answer is an array of

`[2, 3, 5]`  because goods = 1 and is lower than any of the orders

Similarly `if goods = 4` then the answer would be: `[5]`

When this rule is true; only return the highest order value.

Currently I do this via:

```
let lower = orders.filter({goods < $0})
print ("Lower: \(lower)")
// Output is Lower: [2, 3, 5]
```

or to put it more accurately, I use:

```
let lower = orders.filter({goods < $0}).max() ?? 0 as Int
// Output is 5
```

However; this does not get me the index of the `orders` array where this rule is true.

**(c) When higher number rule is valid**

> The player has more goods than the highest order value 
>   showing in the orders array
>
> Post-effect: Only return highest order value && index

Example:

`If goods = 8`

```
let higher = orders.filter({goods > $0 }).max() ?? 0 as Int
print ("Higher: \(higher)")
// Output is: 5
```

However; this does not get me the index of the `orders` array where this rule is true.

Question >

How do I enumerate through the above filters() where .max() is applied to return the array index & array value for the given lowest and higher number rules?

Many thanks

---

Edit:  Update

I've now compiled it into an if-statement;

```
// should only return the first result; regardless of how many results returned
let perfectMatch = orders.enumerated().filter({goods == $0.element}).flatMap({
    [($0.offset, $0.element)]
}).first

if let perfectMatch = perfectMatch {
    print ("Perfect Match: \(perfectMatch)")
}
else {

    let lower = orders.enumerated().max(by: {goods < $1.element}).flatMap({
        [($0.offset, $0.element)]
    })

    if let lower = lower {
        print("Lower \(lower)")
    }
    else {

        let higher = orders.enumerated().max(by: {goods > $1.element}).flatMap({[($0.offset, $0.element)]})

        print("higher \(higher!)")

// if higher fails (unlikely), return a nil 

    }

}
```

The problem is that if goods are higher than any/all numbers, ie: `8` and orders are `[1,1,1]` then the lower boundary should fail / fall through but it always returns

`Lower [(0, 1)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the `enumerated()` instance method on `orders`?

This returns an `EnumeratedSequence`, essentially providing an index value and element value.

```
let orders = [2,3,5]

// goods == 8
let higher = orders.enumerated().max(by: {goods > $1.element}).flatMap({[($0.offset, $0.element)]})
print(higher!) // Prints [(2, 5)]

// goods == 1
let lower = orders.enumerated().filter({goods < $0.element})
print(lower) // Prints [(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5)]

// goods == 4
let lower = orders.enumerated().filter({goods < $0.element})
print(lower) // Prints [(2, 5)]
```

**EDIT:**

Made changes based on your comments.

Order type that encapsulates an `Int` array and your rule checks.

```
struct Order {
    private var _orders: [Int]
    var orders: [Int] {
        return _orders
    }

    init(orders: [Int]) {
        _orders = orders
    }

    func match(_ good: Int) -> (Int, Int)? {
        var match = _orders.enumerated().filter {
            good == $0.element
        }

        match = match.flatMap {
            [($0.offset, $0.element)]
        }
        return match.first
    }

    func lower(_ good: Int) -> (Int, Int)? {
        let lower = _orders.enumerated().max {
            a, b in
            return a.element > b.element
        }

        let upper = _orders.enumerated().max {
            a, b in
            return a.element < b.element
        }

        guard let lowerValue = lower?.1, let upperValue = upper?.1 else {
            return nil
        }

        let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lowerValue, upperValue))
        let inRange = range.contains(good)

        if inRange || good < range.lowerBound {
            return upper
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func higher(_ good: Int) -> (Int, Int)? {
        let upper = _orders.enumerated().max {
            a, b in
            return a.element < b.element
        }

        guard let upperValue = upper?.element else {
            return nil
        }

        if good > upperValue {
            return upper
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var order = Order(orders: [2, 3, 5])
let good = 8

if let match = order.match(good) {
    print("Found match for: \(good) in \(order.orders) at index: \(match.0)")
} else {
    print("No Match.. Checking Lower...")
    if let lower = order.lower(good) {
        print("Found lower for: \(good) in \(order.orders) at index: \(lower.0)")
    } else {
        print("No Lower.. Checking Higher...")
        if let higher = order.higher(good) {
            print("Found higher for: \(good) in \(order.orders) at index: \(higher.0)")
        } else {
            print("Failure.")
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
No Match.. Checking Lower...
No Lower.. Checking Higher...
Found higher for: 8 in [2, 3, 5] at index: 2
```

Comment: This seems to work, however the lower one returns multiple results; when it should return the max() of the returned result.  In this regard, I've copied and inverted the higher filter algorithm you posted and seems to work; and am currently testing various outcomes.

Comment: Hi there. When the goods are 8, the lower boundary check should return nil but it always returns Lower [(0, 1)] which isn't correct;  in other words -- the Lower boundary check should fail if it can't find any matches for its equality comparison

Comment: When I `var orders = [2,6,2]; var goods = 1` the output of the lower tuple is `Lower [(0, 2), (1, 6), (2, 2)]`  - This should only be the highest (1,6) tuple that is returned; the max of the returned filter.

Comment: Thanks for the update; I'll give it a check.  I've was looking at using a for-loop to get around this issue, but I was trying to avoid using for-loops when un-necessary

Comment: Accepted. The tests I've done seem to work. Many thanks for your help and assistance on this.  I can see why you've used a struct for this matter.  Thanks again.